I'm struggling to write a code in r to wrap box plot using a condition called species



species
seed type
germination time




A
initial
10.5


A
initial
11.3


B
stored
12.5



about data
There are 34 species, 2 seed types (stored and initial), germination time is numerical.
What I need to create is something similar to the attached image. The main thing is that it needs to be created using ggplot

I tried to wrap pannels using the following code
plot2 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=factor(species), y=mgt,fill = species))+
  geom_boxplot(outliers = F)+ theme(legend.position = "bottom") 
plot3 <- plot2 + coord_flip()+ facet_wrap(seed_type) + scale_x_discrete(name = "Seed Type") + scale_y_continuous(name = "Germination Time")
plot3  

But it didn't create the figure I wanted.

library(tidyverse)

# create some fake data
my_data <- data.frame(
  species = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
  seed_type = sample(paste0("seed_type_", letters[1:8]), 100, replace = TRUE),
  germination_time = runif(100, 10, 12.5)
)

head(my_data)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = factor(species), y = germination_time, fill = species))+
  geom_boxplot(outliers = F)+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~seed_type, ncol = 4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Species") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Germination Time") 


Thank you for the effort taken!
But I need the species as the wrap, and two seed types represent the two box plots at each panel.

Thank you! I found the way thanks to your code. Thank you again for the efforts.
